# Error using .contains() JQuery function in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I call .contains in

```
if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().contains(word)
```

Chrome returns an error Uncaught TypeError:Object

```
<input id="busca_prof" class="campo_filtro" type="text" name="word" placeholder="pesquisar profissional">

<div id="prof_{{ prof.id }}" class="profissional filtrar">
   ... content
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".campo_filtro").keyup(function(){
        word = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

        $(".filtrar").each(function(){
            if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().contains(word) ||
                removeAcento($(this).text().toUpperCase()).contains(word)){
                $(this).fadeIn();
            }else{
                $(this).fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Chrome does not implement the [String.prototype.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) method just yet. Also, you should declare the `word` variable inside the `keyup` handler, at the minute it's implicitly declared at window scope

Comment: Is this what "contains" is for? I thought it was for parent-child relations in objects...

Comment: yeah contains isnt a string/substring match.. it gives array of elements back.

Comment: wow really? it shouldnt' lol :D maybe in firefox it returns array of strings ? really strange..

Comment: @rayashi It does work in Firefox. As stated in the MDN link I provided. It doesn't work in anything else though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey contains is different in jquery..https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

try this :

```
var txt = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
var contains = (txt.indexOf(word) > -1);
```

that'll give you a bool in contains.

**EDIT**
heres your new code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".campo_filtro").keyup(function(){
    word = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

    $(".filtrar").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(word) != -1 ||
            removeAcento($(this).text().toUpperCase()).indexOf(word) != -1){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }else{
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: np - Accept the answer if it helped you :) @rayashi